# Can I mount two USB3 'flash' thumb-drives in a RAID configuration?

Tags: usb-drive, raid

I am asking before I buy... I am getting a new Chromebook to run Ubuntu on. For storage I would like to use the two USB ports with a thumb-drive in each (I don't plan on using any other USB doodads).

Can I use two identical USB3 thumb-drives and mount them in a RAID configuration, thereby doubling the speed?

Comment: Why use Flash disks and not actual SSD or HDD?

Comment: @Virusboy - Sadly chromebooks don't have anything like 'drive bays' as it is all supposed to be 'in the cloud'.

Comment: You can use external HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, but it is not going to be a good solution. You can add pretty much every block device to a software RAID. But the limitations of that device will limit the whole array. In case of USB the limiting factors are speed (yes, even with USB 3.0) and reliability. Also the devices will have to be plugged in all the time. If one is not accessible even for a short time, the RAID will be degraded and has to be rebuilt. This might take hours. So, there is no hot-plugging.

Overall what you are trying to do can work, but it is no recommended and your goal of getting more speed will not be reached.

It you need extra USB RAID storage for your computer: there are dual hard drive enclosures on the market that can combine the drive to a RAID and have USB 3.0 connectors. Unluckily they will need external power.